# Как полностью копировать контрол winForms?

Tags: winforms, .net, c#

То есть имеется собственный контрол, наследуемый от класса Control. Нужно создать несколько его копий, именно копий, а не ссылок на него. Т.к. надо каждый из них поместить на разные панели.

Comment: Понял, что это делать не стоит...

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так:

```
void Copy(Control source, Control destination)
{
  var pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source);

  // Копируем значения всех свойств
  foreach(PropertyDescriptor pd in pdc)
  {
    if (!pd.IsReadOnly)
      pd.SetValue(destination, pd.GetValue(source));
  }

  // Создаём копии вложенных контролов и копируем содержания
  foreach (Control ctrl in source.Controls)
  {
    var ctrl2 = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(ctrl.GetType());
    Copy(ctrl, ctrl2);
    ctrl2.Visible = true;
    destination.Controls.Add(ctrl2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Варианты:

1. Сделать свой контрол на основе [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) и, создавая новые экземпляры во время исполнения, добавлять их на панели.
2. Реализовать интерфейс [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icloneable(v=VS.100).aspx) в контроле, который будет копировать полное содержимое.

Если цель - динамическое добавление контролов во время работы программы, то первый вариант предпочтительнее.